# can I recovery specific table from .DBF files in oracle?

Tags: oracle, restore, recovery

I have oracle 19c on windows10, I accidentally corrupted my System TABLESPACE file([Description](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/328086/255663)). But my USERS tablespace Not damaged, Can I recovery my tables from this file on windows?

I haven't any Rman backup file or Archive log.

[image]

Comment: Realistically, no.  If you don't have a valid backup, the data is lost.  Oracle Consulting and a very, very small number of third party firms have written tools that may be able to recover some or all of the data from raw data files.  Those are **extremely** expensive tools aimed at large organizations that are willing to write very large checks to recover data when all their backups are corrupted.